# Beginner C++ having trouble understanding a parameter in all my teachers functions

Tags: c++, function, parameters

Question: what is this string prompt my teacher keeps using?

My teacher made this header file with tools prototypes:

```
#include<string>
//using namespace std;

#ifndef TOOLS_LOCK
#define TOOLS_LOCK

namespace tools_namespace
{
extern const int SCREEN_WIDTH;

std::string swab( char value, int howMany );
void    pause( std::string prompt );
void    flush(void);
int     getInt          ( std::string prompt );
float   getFloat        ( std::string prompt );
char    getChar         ( std::string prompt );
std::string getString   ( std::string prompt );
std::string getLine     ( std::string prompt );
bool    getBool         ( std::string prompt );
int     getBoundedInt   ( std::string prompt,
                            int lowerBound,
                            int upperBound );
int getPositiveInt      ( std::string prompt );
int getNonNegativeInt   ( std::string prompt );
void handleInputError   ( std::string message );

int width       ( int number );
int magnitude   ( int value );
int minimum( int a, int b );
int maximum( int a, int b );

bool isOdd( int value );
}
#endif
```

Now here is the tools.cpp with the actual tools with the math. I'm about to take a test later and we have to use his getNonNegativeInt function found at line 123. The thing throwing me off is this "string prompt" everywhere in this code.

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include"Tools.h"
#include"CompileSwitches.h"
using namespace std;

namespace tools_namespace
{
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 80;

string swab( char swabValue, int howMany )
{
    string swabString;
    for ( int charsNeeded = howMany
            ; charsNeeded > 0
            ; --charsNeeded )
        swabString = swabString + swabValue;
    return swabString;
}

void pause( string prompt )
{
    cout << prompt;
    cin.ignore(999,'\n');
}

// clear input garbage
void flush( void )
{
    cin.ignore(999,'\n');
}

int getInt( string prompt )
{
    int userInput;
    while (true)
    {
        cout << prompt;
        cin >> userInput;
        flush();
        if ( !cin.fail() ) break;
        handleInputError("Non-Numeric input.");
    }
    return userInput;
}

float getFloat( string prompt )
{
    float userInput;
    while (true)
    {
        cout << prompt;
        cin >> userInput;
        flush();
        if ( !cin.fail() ) break;
        handleInputError("Non-Numeric input.");
    }
    return userInput;
}

int magnitude ( int value )
{
    return (value>=0) ? value : -value;
}

int width( int number )
{
    int digitCount = 0;
    if ( number < 0 )
    {
        ++digitCount; // for the sign
        number = -number;
    }
    for ( ; number >= 10 ; number /= 10 )
        ++digitCount;
    ++digitCount; // for the last digit
    return digitCount;
}

int minimum( int a, int b )
{
    return ( a < b ) ? a : b;
    //if ( a < b )
    //  return a;
    //else
    //  return b;
}

int maximum( int a, int b )
{
    return ( a > b ) ? a : b;
    //if ( a < b )
    //  return a;
    //else
    //  return b;
}

int getBoundedInt( string prompt,
                    int lowerBound, int higherBound )
{
    int userInput;
    while (true)
    {
        userInput = getInt( prompt );
        if ( userInput >= lowerBound
                && userInput <= higherBound )
            break;
        cout << "Value must be in the range "
                << lowerBound
                << "..."
                << higherBound
                << ". Try again."
                << endl;
    }
    return userInput;
}

int getPositiveInt( string prompt )
{
    return getBoundedInt( prompt, 1, INT_MAX );
}

int getNonNegativeInt( string prompt )
{
    return getBoundedInt( prompt, 0, INT_MAX );
}

char getChar( string prompt )
{
    char userInput;
    while (true)
    {
        cout << prompt;
        cin >> userInput;
        flush();
        if ( !cin.fail() ) break;
        handleInputError("Input failed.");
    }
    return userInput;
}

string getString( string prompt )
{
    string userInput;
    while (true)
    {
        cout << prompt;
        cin >> userInput;
        flush();
        if ( !cin.fail() ) break;
        handleInputError("Input failed.");
    }
    return userInput;
}

void handleInputError( string message )
{
    cin.clear();
    flush();
    cout << message << " Try again." << endl;
}

string getLine( string prompt )
{
    string userInput;
    while (true)
    {
        cout << prompt;
        getline(cin,userInput);
        if ( !cin.fail() ) break;
        cin.clear();
        flush();
        cout << "Input failed - Try again." << endl;
    }
    return userInput;
}

bool getBool( string prompt )
{
    while (true)
    {
        char userInput = getChar(prompt);
        if ( userInput == 'y' || userInput == 'Y' )
            return true;
        if ( userInput == 'n' || userInput == 'N' )
            return false;
        cout << "Please enter y or n." << endl;
    }
}

bool isOdd( int aNumber )
{
#ifndef GROSS
    return magnitude(aNumber)%2 == 1;
#else
    if ( aNumber < 0 )
        aNumber = -aNumber;
    int remainder = aNumber%2;
    if ( remainder == 1 || remainder == -1)
        return true;
    else if ( remainder != 1 )
        return false;
#endif
}
}
```

Comment: ...those are just function arguments...

Comment: It's just an `std::string` called `prompt`. I don't get the question.

Comment: [*Prompt* from Wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prompt): A reminder or cue.  You pass the prompt and it is displayed to ask the user to enter a value.

Comment: What I'm more curious about is how your teacher came up with `cin.ignore(999,'\n');` and why he teaches you to use `using namespace std;`.

Comment: Its just a variable from the `std` namespace, of the `string` data type, and its name is `prompt`, just a string that's being passed into the function call for further processing

Comment: isnt that another word for parameter? and im confused cause in int getInt he actually cout << prompt. but i dont see anywhere he making prompt outputing anything.

Comment: @Baird don't be so concerned about the variable name, its just a string, every one of those functions could say `func(std::string x)` and it would be the same thing, the important part is that its a `string` argument being passed to your function

Comment: @Baird think of `prompt` as a command in the form of a `string`, so if `prompt = "Enter a number"` then that can be displayed over and over again to the user until said user enters a valid number, etc

Comment: *Prompt* is not a synonym for parameter.  See my link to Wikitionary.  A parameter is a "variable" you pass to a function. A prompt is used to ask a User for data or an action.

Comment: no i didnt say same as prompt the guy said its a fucntion argument... and i was like thats no help because isnt argument just another name for parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the question is what is string prompt, it is just a string variable where the name of the string variable is "prompt" that is passed into the function when the function is called.  For example:

```
std::string thisIsAString = "Hello World";

void PrintPromptText(std::string prompt){
   std::cout << prompt;
}
int main(void){
PrintPromptText(thisIsAString);
return 0;
}
```

The output of this code would be "Hello World"

Your teacher is just using prompt as the variable name for a string variable.

Answer (score 0):

The prompt (as I guessing by the name) is text that is printed before inputting of data.

For example:

```
int my_variable = getInt("Enter an integer: ");
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument `string prompt` is used by the functions that take it to ask the program user to give input, in the line `cout << prompt`.

The function `getNonNegativeInt(string prompt)` uses the string as stated above, then will only accept user input if it is in the range 0-INT_MAX(i.e. positive) through calling `getBoundedInt(string prompt, int lowerBound, int upperBound)` with the correct arguments. INT_MAX is a macro defined constant that does what its name suggests.